# Displaying information from another model on index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*Noob warning - learning MVC for an academic project* :-)

I have two models and I'm trying to show ProjectName (from first model) in my index view of Actors (from my second model). Everything loads up OK and I'm able to display projectId from my Actor class, but it's not picking up a value for `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project.ProjectName)` in my index table.

However, it is picking up the correct `[DisplayName("Project Name")` in the table, which makes me think it is making some connection - just can't understand why it's not getting the value for it, I just have an empty column with a correctly labelled header!

I had planned on using a ViewModel to achieve this, but in the Wrox Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 book, the authors do what appears to be the same as what I am attempting in showing the Genre & Artist names (not ID's) in their Album view (MVC Music Store project - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4).

Help much appreciated!

```
 public class Project
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [DisplayName ("Project Name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Client")]    
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Use Cases")]
    public virtual ICollection <UseCase> UseCases { get; set; }
```

}

...

```
 public class Actor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int projectID { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller code for the Index action (note, I'm passing the projectId in the URL and this is what I'm using as the parameter...

```
// GET: Actors
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.projectId = id;
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Actors.Where(x => x.projectID == id).ToList());
        }
    }
```

And here is the view code....

```
   @model IEnumerable<JustSpecIt.Models.Actor>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Actors";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Actors</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = ViewBag.projectId })
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.project.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.projectID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project.ProjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

@Html.ActionLink("<< Back", "ShowSteps", "Projects", new { id = ViewBag.projectId }, null)
```

Comment: If `projectID` is correct the navigation property should be correct as well. Probably change it to: `public virtual Project project { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Are you sure property `project` is not null and that `ProjectName` has a value?

Comment: Added the view and controller code as requested. Just going to debug through now and see if project actually gets populated. I have a column for projectId on my index and this is populated...but let me do some digging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `virtual` keyword to `project` property in `Actor` class to allow lazy loading of the related `Project`

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int projectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project project { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

See here for more info regarding lazy loading related entities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy

Comment: Great that did it! Time for me to go read up about `virtual`, hopefully I can understand why this made it work! Thanks @ekad

Comment: Thanks, checked out the link and up-voted. One final question - when using lazy loading like this, when does it become appropriate to use `include` in my LINQ query to avoid N+1 problems?

Comment: I'd say it's appropriate when `N` is large or you want to display a lot of the related entities in your view. See here for more info: [Select N+1 Problem – How to Decrease Your ORM Performance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/08/18/select-n1-problem-how-to-decrease-your-orm-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [DisplayName ("Project Name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Client")]    
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Use Cases")]
    public virtual ICollection <UseCase> UseCases { get; set; } 
}

public class Actor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int projectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project project { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

// GET: Actors
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.projectId = id;
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }


    using (var context = new DbContext()) // initiate a connection to the DB
    {
        var actors = context.Actors.Where(x => x.projectID == id);

        // tell it to include the projects
        actors.Include("project"); // the name of the property

        // now retrieve list from the DB
        actors.ToList();

        // return the actors to the view
        return View(actors);
    }
 }
```

So the `DbContext` is what ever you context is called. We wrap it in a using to let make sure we manage the connection properly.

The `virtual` keyword in front of `Project project {get;set;}` is to enable Lazy loading, which can be bad in some cases (Causes SELECT N + 1 problems). To make sure we include all the projects in our list of actors we use the `Include` function and pass the name of the property through.

To bypass issues with SELECT N + 1, we call the `ToList()` method before we pass the values to the view. If we don't then the view will execute the get actors SQL and for each actor it will execute a call to get the project. So if we have 10 actors, we will make 11 calls. Which isn't good. `ToList()` makes sure that we execute 1 call, that provides us with all the values we will need in the view.

Then we execute the DB call with `ToList()`. And pass the values back to the view.